# object not visible Qtp error

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I have a Smalltalk application screen and need to automate it. It has n number of Radio button , combo box,txt box. I have created DP for it and entering values. but as soon it select one radio button for next it fails with next giving object not found error.
I have entered used WaitProperty visiblity true 25000 still it fails. It is also skipping edit box for entering values and jumping to next box.

Comment: Can you give some more information?  Debugger info? A link to a screen shot?

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for this. This happens because windows objects are not visible untill u access entire screen. You must scroll to end and return back to top for allowing DP to catupre entire objects.